# Find top common value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get the top common date group by code and item. Is there anyway I can achieve this in snowflake?

My current table looks something like this. I need to extract out the date that is available in all item for each code. For e.g. for code = 1, I only want date = 2022-03-01 because it's the only date that is common between item a,b,c.

| Code | Date | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | a |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | a |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | b |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | b |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | c |
| 1 | 2022-05-01 | c |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | a |
| 2 | 2022-05-01 | a |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | b |
| 2 | 2022-03-01 | b |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | c |

My end result:

| Code | Date | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | a |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | b |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 | c |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | a |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | b |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | c |

Comment: Your logic is not clear.  For code 1, you select the latest date records, while for code 2 you select the earliest ones.  Please explain.

Comment: Hi, have updated my qns with more details

Answer (score 0):

You may use count window function to count the similar dates for each code, then use the desne_rank function to get the rows with date value equal to the date with max count.

```
with count_dates as
(
  select *, 
    count(*) over (partition by Code, Date) cn
  from table_name
)
select Code, Date, item
from
(
  select *,
     dense_rank() over (partition by Code order by cn desc) rnk
  from count_dates
) T
where rnk=1
order by Code
```

Using `dense_rank() over (partition by Code order by cn desc) rnk` will return all the latest common dates (dates with with same maximum count value), if you want to get only the latest common date use `dense_rank() over (partition by Code order by cn desc, Date desc) rnk`.

Output:

[image]

Comment: What if I have multiple dates with the same value? How do I ensure that the latest date be picked?

Comment: I updated the answer to cover this requirement.

Comment: I just noticed your edit, *I need to extract out the date that is available in all item for each code*; what if the date is missing from one item and has the max count, should it be considered as the common date?